# Trying to add both example.com and www.example.com to github pages website

Tags: git, github-pages, nameservers

I'm using namesilo and I'm having a bit of a hard time figuring this one out - In the settings screen on github I see the possibility for me to add a custom domain, which I have done, everything is working great for example.com with the a record i set up, and I've created the cname record on namesilo.

However when I entered the custom domain on github it created a cname file in my master branch with example.com in it and now I'm a bit stuck on what I should do, any input would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I'm not 100% sure how I did it but now www.example.com is redirecting to example.com, I suppose this is a result of removing the parking cname from namesilo and adding the repo name instead (username.github.io). Any idea how I can make it redirect to www.example.com? Is it at as simple as changing the custom domain on the repo settings to www.example.com?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out a while back and decided I should come back here and answer the question in case someone else ran across the same problem.

All I had to do was change the custom domain in the repository settings to www.example.com and now example.com redirects to www.example.com. Just make sure you change your a name records and cname records on your DNS provider.